# Laravel 4 under Nginx Proxy Reverse

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setting two Laravel apps...there is a main app and an API, which must run under a path

Main App URI: http://subdomain.domain.com
API App URI: http://subdomain.domain.com/api/

So, here the Nginx Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    ssl on;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/main_project/current/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_ADMIN_VALUE    "open_basedir=none";
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS  on;
    }

}


server {
    listen 81;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/api_project/current/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

The issue is: routing under API app is not working. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the path split directive in the second server fastcgi block. 
Try modifying it in the following way :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
 }
```